# Error management/skip to top level function - Python

Tags: python, python-2.6

I am devising an error-return System for my program which parses a file. I have the main function

```
headerDict, paramDict, modelDict,error = parse(fPath)
```

which takes a file path and then calls parse(), which Returns three dictionaries and an error (0 for everythign ok, numbers for the different error types, Errors are defined in the subfunctions).
parse is a function that calls several sub-functions which return an error:

```
def parse(fPath):
    content, error = read_file(fPath)

    header, body, error = prepare_file(content)

    headerDict, error = make_headerDict(header)

    paramDict, modelDict, error = make_bodyDicts(body)

    return headerDict, paramDict, modelDict, error
```

Now I would like to check after each sub-function call if error is still Zero, if yes continue with the next sub-function, if not jump to the main function with the error value where it will be handled. I could obviously insert

```
if not error:
    pass
else:
    headerDict = {}
    paramDict = {}
    modelDict = {}
    return headerDict, paramDict, modelDict, error
```

after each sub-function call in the parse() function, but isn't there a more elegant way to do this? I thought of writing an error_check function containing the above code, but then I don't know how to return directly to the main function and not to the parse function.

Please Keep in mind that I don't want to raise exceptions etc. during the program and cause it to stop and Exit, I want the program to run until the end (e.g. main) and return the error value then. (And also sorry for the bad title, was not sure how to express my Problem... ;) )

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

This is what exceptions are for. Define a custom exception - it can just be an empty class inheriting from the base Exception class - and each of your sub functions can raise that error when they need to. Your main function can then wrap everything in a try/except block - making sure to only catch your custom exception - so that if any of them raises, execution will skip straight to the except clause.

Comment: okay that sounds reasonable, I hadn't thought about custom exceptions... I will look into it, thanks!